# bash script execution date/time

Tags: linux, bash, date

I'm trying to figure this out on and off for some time now. I have a bash script in Linux environment that, for safety reasons, I want to prevent from being executed say between 9am and 5pm unless a flag is given. So if I do ./script.sh between 9am and 5pm it would say "NO GO", but if I do ./script.sh -force it would bypass the check. Basically making sure the person doesn't do something by accident. I've tried some date commands, but can't wrap that thing around my mind. Could anyone help out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function. Use `date +"%k"` to get the current hour, and `(( ))` to compare it.

Comment: It evaluates an arithmetic expression in bash. `help '(('`

Comment: OK, I have this. Would that work:


HOUR=$((`date +"%k"`))
if (( HOUR >= 9 && HOUR <= 18 )) && [ "$1" != "-force" ] ; then
    echo "NO GO"
    exit
fi


echo "GOING..."

Comment: `HOUR=$(date +"%k")` and don't forget the `else` on the if.

Comment: Actually, With the exit you don't need the else, so skip that. I blame that on this tiny comment space. I do recommend e.g. `exit 1` though.

Comment: There'd need to be newlines or semi-colons in the script; I can see one semi-colon, but newlines were probably flattened by the lack of formatting in the comment mechanism.

Comment: Somehow newlines didnt make it in the comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Basic answer:

```
case "$1" in
(-force)
    : OK;;
(*)
    case $(date +'%H') in
    (09|1[0-6]) 
        echo "Cannot run between 09:00 and 17:00" 1>&2
        exit 1;;
    esac;;
esac
```

Note that I tested this (a script called 'so.sh') by running:

```
TZ=US/Pacific sh so.sh
TZ=US/Central sh so.sh
```

It worked in Pacific time (08:50) and not in Central time (10:50).  The point about this is emphasizing that your controls are only as good as your environment variables.  And users can futz with environment variables.

Comment: You can improve your chances if your date command has `--utc` which should make it ignore the time zone.

Comment: Yes, but then you need to know which time range to allow in UTC.  Does the colleague in US/Eastern need the same time range ban as the colleague in US/Pacific time?  Is it from 09:00 US/Eastern to 17:00 US/Pacific?  Are the times in PST or PDT (Standard/Daylight Saving Time?)

Comment: I like the use of case hear. The alternative is test. In the case of $1, case avoids the need for testing if the length of $1 is zero before testing if it is "-force". I avoid it with `[ "${1}-" = "-forced-" ]`

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ensure environmental variable runprogram=yes isn't set before 
unset runprogram 

# logic works out to don't run if between 9 and 5pm as you requested
[ $(date "+%k")  -le 9 -a  $(date +"%k")  -ge 17 ] && runprogram=yes  

# Adding - avoids the need to test if the length of $1 is zero
[ "${$1}-" = "-forced-" ] && runprogram=yes 

if [ "${runprogram}-" = "yes-" ]; then 
    run_program 
else 
    echo "No Go" 1>&2 #redirects message to standard error
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOUR=$(date +%k)
echo "Now hour is $HOUR"

if [[ $HOUR -gt 9 ]] ; then
  echo 'after 9'
fi


if [[ $HOUR -lt 23 ]]; then
  echo 'before 11 pm'
fi
```